# Why does my function execute when I push it onto a JS array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I ran across this problem when trying to populate a JS array for some animation I'm doing....the following Javascript function is invoked when I click a link within my web page for testing purposes:

```
function testing()
{
    var funcArray = [];
    var testFunc = function(){console.log("test function");}

    funcArray.push(function(){console.log("hello there");});
    funcArray.push(testFunc());
}
```

When this executes, I get "test function" to appear in the JS console, but not "hello there". Why does pushing the predefined testFunc cause output, but not the inline function in the first push?

Comment: Remove the function brackets. Only push the name, `funcArray.push(testFunc);`

Comment: Cause you are executing th function using ()

Comment: Understood. Thanks much.

Answer (score 6):

Because you're calling it.

```
funcArray.push(testFunc());
```

*calls* testFunc, then pushes the *result* of that call into funcArray. You probably want `funcArray.push(testFunc);` (note the omitted `()`), which just pushes the function reference to that array.

Answer (score 1):

Because you execute it in `funcArray.push(testFunc());`... What you want is `funcArray.push(testFunc);` Because `testFunc()` executes the Function, takes the return and pushes it to the Array, while `testFunc` takes the actual function to push.